# Basic Combinatorics Choices Question

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having some trouble with the question below:

[image]

I believe the student to have 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 = 3024 choices overall. However I am unsure how to calculate part (a) and (b) of the question.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

Your initial calculation is missing a piece. Since we're choosing items from a list, but the order of items doesn't matter, then you need to use the combinations formula. $9*8*7*6$ would be correct if the order in which the modules were chosen mattered.

Instead, use the following formula:$$\binom nk = \frac {n!}{k!*(n-k)!}$$
$n$ = total number of items (in this case, $9$), $k$ = number of itmes you are choosing (in this case $4$).

For part a of the question, you have a restriction - you need to pick 2 of the 4 math modules and 2 of the 5 computing modules. You can calculate each of these individually (just like you did above for the overall number) and then multiply.

For part b, just like in part a you can calculate the number of ways to do 1 math and 3 computing modules, then 2 math and 2 computing modules, then 3 math and 1 computing, etc. It's generally easier in a question like this, though, to calculate the *opposite* of what we want and subtract from the total.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have calculated the following so far: 72576 total choices and 960 choices for part (a), does this look correct?

Comment: And 2996 choices for part (b)

Comment: Your numbers are way too high. How'd you calculate the total choices?

Comment: so for the initial part, (total choices) i did    9! / (9-4)!4! which gives 72576

Comment: Redo your calculations. That formula is correct, but it should yield an answer of 126.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Your computation of the total number of choices would be correct if it mattered what order he did the modules.  I believe order does not matter-only what modules are selected.   For $a$, as you are selecting four modules, you have to select two of each kind.  How many ways are there to select two math modules?  Two computing modules?  For $b$, you can subtract the number of choices that do not include a math module from the total number.

Answer (score 0):

Part (a):

2 computing modules out of 5 can be chosen in $ ^{5}C_{2}$ ways

2 math modules out of 4 can be chosen in $ ^{4}C_{2}$ ways

if one thing can be done in $m$ ways and another thing can be done in $n$ ways, then both things together can be done in $mn$ ways.

So the total number of ways in which equal number of comp and math modules can be chosen in (multiply above numbers) ways.

Part(b:)

At least 1 math module is possible in following ways:

(choose 1 math AND choose 3 comp) module OR (choose 2 math AND choose 2 comp) module OR (choose 3 math AND choose 1 comp) module OR (choose 4 math AND choose 0 comp) module

Replace AND with multiplication(*),

Replace OR with summation(+)